# Out of memory error when reading a large file

Tags: php, loops, csv, error-handling, fgetcsv

I have a large csv that I want to parse and insert into my database. I have this PHP:

```
$target = '../uploads/'.$f;
$handle = fopen($target, "r");
$data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",");

$rows = array();

while ($data !== FALSE) {
    $rows[] =  $data;
}

fclose($handle);

if (count($rows)) {
             foreach ($rows as $key => $value) {

                  echo $value;

              }
          }
```

Every time I try to run my script I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 35 bytes)
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this part is wrong:

```
$data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",");
$rows = array();
while ($data !== FALSE) {
    $rows[] =  $data;
}
```

One call to `fgetcsv` reads one line from `$handle`. You need to put `fgetcsv` in the loop condition:

```
$handle = fopen($target, "r");
$data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",");
while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    // Example insert - obviously use prepared statements/escaping/another DAL
    $db->query("INSERT INTO tbl (columns..) VALUES ({$row[0]}, {$row[1]} ... )");
}
```

Comment: Ok, this stopped the fatal error. The thing now is that it echos this long list of "Array" instead of the actual values.

Comment: `$data` is an array of fields in one row, which you can check with `print_r($data)` or `var_dump($data)`.

Comment: Then how do you $rows so that you get each value so that you can insert it into the database?

Comment: I updated my answer, as xdazz said you don't need to read the whole file into another array, only to loop over it again.

Comment: This still gives the Fatal error of exceeding the allowed memory size.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to read all csv data from the file into memory before processing.

Instead, create a while loop that reads from your file one line at a time.  Each time you read from the file, you should insert a row into your database.

Or read several lines and insert several rows at one time.

**Example:**

```
   $i = 0; 
   while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",") !== FALSE) {
        $rows[] = $data;
        $i++;
        // insert 100 rows at one time.
        if ($i % 100 === 0) {
            //insert these rows to db
            insert_to_db($rows);
            //then reset $rows
            $rows = array();
        }
    }
    insert_to_db($rows);
```

Comment: Ok, so how would you suggest I loop through rows to insert them in the db? I want each row to be a row in the db. I tried this to loop through: `foreach($rows as $key => $value){echo $value.'</br>';}`, but came out with just a list of "Array".

Comment: @chromedude you are `echo`ing `$value` which is nothing related with saving the data to db, just find a tutorial that show you how to put the data into the db.

Comment: If you follow this approach, do not forget to make one more insert_to_db($rows) call after the loop to insert the remainder.

Answer (score 5):

### Use mysqlimport instead

While you can certainly parse and build queries with PHP you'll get much better performance by letting MySQL handle it directly.  Your database will thank you.

```
<?php
exec("mysqlimport mysqlimport [options] db_name textfile1");
?>
```

Sources:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html

Answer (score 4):

Use standard MySQL [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html) statement to escape reading/parsing/inserting data via PHP:

```
 function import_csv( $table, $afields, $filename, $delim = ',', $enclosed = '"', $escaped = '\\',  $lineend = '\\r\\n', $hasheader = FALSE) {      
    if ( $hasheader ) $ignore = "IGNORE 1 LINES ";
    else $ignore = "";
    $q_import = 
        "LOAD DATA INFILE '" . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $filename . "' INTO TABLE " . $table . " " .
        "FIELDS TERMINATED BY '" . $delim . "' ENCLOSED BY '" . $enclosed . "' " .
        "    ESCAPED BY '" . $escaped . "' " .
        "LINES TERMINATED BY '" . $lineend . "' " . $ignore . "(" . implode(',', $afields) . ")"
    ;
    return mysql_query($q_import);
}
```

In this case you don't need to open/read CSV file in PHP, MySQL will handle data import by itself.